# Why it's not possible to write extention function on Kotlin enum

Tags: kotlin

I have the below code which works fine.

```
enum class Test() {
    TestOne,
    TestTwo
}

fun main() {
    Test.values().forEach{ item -> println(item) }
}
```

Output:

```
TestOne
TestTwo
```

Now I would like to create an extension function for the enum class receiver type `Test` to print those values like below

```
enum class Test() {
    TestOne,
    TestTwo
}

fun Test.printAllValues() {
    this.values().forEach{ item -> println(item) }
}

fun main() {
    Test.printAllValues()
}
```

But it throws a type ambiguity error.

```
Unresolved reference: values
Overload resolution ambiguity: public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
Overload resolution ambiguity: public inline fun println(message: Any?): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: Boolean): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: Byte): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: CharArray): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: Double): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: Float): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: Int): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: Long): Unit defined in kotlin.io public inline fun println(message: Short): Unit defined in kotlin.io
Unresolved reference: printAllValues
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extension function is defined such that the receiver is an **instance** of a class, not the name of a class. Inside your extension function, `this` is an **instance** of Test. You can't call `values()` on instances of an enum. It's a special function that is called on the name of the enum class. So, you have to call it as `Test.values()`, not `this.values()`.

But, since you can only call it on an instance of a class, your syntax `Test.printAllValues()` will not work. You have to call your extension function on one of the *instances* of Test, such as `Test.TestOne.printAllValues()`.

```
fun Test.printAllValues() {
    Test.values().forEach{ item -> println(item) }
}

fun main() {
    Test.TestOne.printAllValues()
}
```

In this case, that doesn't really make conceptual sense. To be able to define this extension function to work on the **name** Test, you need to give your enum a `companion object`, and you can define the function either as a member of this companion object, or as an extension on that companion. This takes advantage of the fact that the companion object's sole *instance* can be referred to by using the name of the class it is the companion of.

```
enum class Test() {
    TestOne,
    TestTwo;
    companion object {
        fun printAllValues() {
            Test.values().forEach{ item -> println(item) }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
enum class Test() {
    TestOne,
    TestTwo;
    companion object
}

fun Test.Companion.printAllValues() {
    Test.values().forEach{ item -> println(item) }
}
```